# making backbone models & collections available globally using requireJS

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, backbone-views, backbone-routing

i am a newbie to web application development. i have a backbone model named LoginModel. I want to create an object of it  and make it globally accessible from any Backbone View which will be loaded dynamically. Here is my model..

```
define(['underscore', 'backbone'], function(_, Backbone) {
    LoginModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        initialize: function(){ },
        defaults:{
            userName: 'undefined',
            userID: 'undefined'
        },
        urlRoot: 'https://xxxx.xx.xxxxxx',
        parse: function(response, options){
            return{
                userName: response.userName,
                userId:response.userId
            };
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: fyi, your `LoginModel` is already global and because you forgot to put the `var` declaration before the variable name.

Comment: @gion_13 So will it work without initializing it again in above case ?
how to call parse method for LoginModel in above case ?

Comment: I don't think I'm getting what you want. You just instantiate the model (`var myLoginModelInstance = new LoginModel()`) and then call the `parse` method (`myLoginModelInstance.parse()`).

Answer (score 5):

You could pin the newly created object to an already existing global object that you're using, such as `Backbone` :

```
Backbone.Model.definitions = {
    loginModel : Backbone.Model.extend({...})
}
```

and the use it as this :

```
new View({model : Backbone.Model.definitions.loignModel});
```

It may not be the *shortest* way, but it's cleaner than polluting the global namespace with different variables.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than attaching to the `Backbone.Model` prototype or to the global `window` scope, I find it effective to attach it to a separate `app` object (provided by backbone-boilerplate and most other implementations).

You `app` object then can be required into any other module that requires access to the current user context.

### app/app.js

```
define(function(require, exports, module) {
    "use strict";

    var app = module.exports;

    // Initialize configuration and context objects
    app.root = "/";
    app.currentUser = null; //will be initialized in app/main.js
});
```

### app/main.js

```
require(["config"], function() {
    require(["app", "LoginModel", "router"], function(app, models, Router) {
        app.currentUser = new LoginModel();
        app.currentUser.fetch();

        app.router = new Router();
    })
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Just create a global instance of the model, for example

```
var globalLoginModel = new LoginModel();
```

or

```
window.globalLoginModel = new LoginModel();
```

Then just pass it into any view that you want to use it in, for example

```
new View1({ model : globalLoginModel });
new View2({ model : globalLoginModel });
new View3({ model : globalLoginModel });
```

That should be it.

D